# callback function in ctypes python3 runs only once

Tags: python, c++, callback, ctypes, pyqt5

We are developing a medical camera that generates images (25 frames per second) that are sent to a python Qt application. I am running into a brick wall trying to get the sequence of images from the camera. Each frame is processed by a callback function and after that by a frameprocessor.

We are running under Windows 7 64 bit and python3

We have the following c++ header:

```
DC_API  signed int Start(const ImageConfig * cfg, 
                  void (*NewImage)(const char * image, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int frameNumber, unsigned long long frameTime));
```

Which I am using in python as:

```
def __init__(self, frame_processor ):
    self.callback_frame_processor = frame_processor
    def new_image(image, width, height, framenbr, frametime):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.frametime = frametime
        self.framenr = framenbr
        self.callback_frame_processor(image)
    self.new_image_function = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE( None, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char), ctypes.c_int,
                                       ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_longlong )
    self.callback_function = self.new_image_function(new_image)
```

The frameprocessor is:

```
def start_grabbing_frames(self):
    f = self._preparecall('Start')
    image_config_struct, image_config_pointer = self._fill_image_config()
    f.argtypes = [image_config_pointer, self.new_image_function]
    return self.process_errorcodes(f(ctypes.byref(image_config_struct), self.callback_function))
```

The frameprocessor is:

```
def camera_callback(self, raw_image, width, height):
    qt_image = QImage(raw_image, width, height, QImage.Format.RGB888)
    qpixmap = QPixmap(width, height)
    pix = qpixmap.fromImage(qt_image)
    self.emit(pix)
```

The problem is that it seems that the image is not a valid frame (len(raw_image) is 13036022 while width is 2208 and height is 1648). This results in a hanging application where no image is shown.

Comment: You call `self.callback_frame_processor(image)`, without passing the width and height parameters. Did you forget to include part of your code? How are you creating the `raw_image` argument? The width and height are critical since the `POINTER(c_char)` just points at the first byte without telling us how big the buffer is.

Comment: Hi Eryksun, i think you identified the actual problem. Maybe you can help me a little more. I don't know how to convert the pointer to the actual image using the width and height.

Comment: In the `new_image` callback, I'd first try to to create an array view on the data (not a copy): `raw_image  = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char * (width * height)).from_buffer(image)[0]`. `QImage` may not accept that if it doesn't grok the buffer protocol. In that case copy the array to `bytes` using a slice, e.g. `raw_image[:]`.

Comment: This works thanks a ton!!